# ~/.conda/envs vs. ~/anaconda3/envs

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I was debugging some issues with Anaconda after an update to macOS Catalina recently and noticed that `~/.conda/envs` was added to the configuration. This has broken a number dev environments for me, and I'm wondering...

Why am I seeing this new location for conda environments? Can I remove it and continue to use and create environments solely in `~/anaconda3/envs`?

```
conda info
...
envs directories : /Users/me/.conda/envs
                   /Users/me/anaconda3/envs
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5388#issuecomment-302893917), the purpose of `~/.conda/envs` is to provide conda with at least one directory that is guaranteed to be writable by the user.

> The `~/.conda` directory is no longer used on Windows, only unix. Conda's install location is not guaranteed to be user-writable. Conda always needs at least one user-writable location for the package cache (pkgs directory) and the envs directory where new named environments are created. The default location for these directories is `~/.conda` on unix, and on Windows we use appdirs. The `~/.conda` directory has been used for years on unix for this purpose.
>
> When conda's install location is user-writable, then that's the location chosen as "first writable" for these two directories. When conda's install location is not writable by the current user, then conda uses the `~/.conda` directory as the writable location, but is still able to use the install location for a read-only package cache and named environments. Compare output of `conda config --show` for the two different cases.
>
> The locations of these directories can be overrode by configuration using the `envs_dirs` and `pkgs_dirs` configuration parameters, or `CONDA_ENVS_DIRS` and `CONDA_PKGS_DIRS` environment variables.

It should be safe to install environments only into `~/anaconda3/envs`, as long as that is writable by the current user. For example, I only install environments into `~/miniconda3/envs` and have faced no issues.