# Windows 10 conda env creation in pycharm and Anaconda Prompt are different

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, interpreter, anaconda3

I created a ***`conda env from Anaconda Prompt`*** and named it as "Abrechnung". It creates and saves in

```
C:\Users\<name>\.conda\envs\Abrechnung
```

I can use it by typing

```
conda activate Abrechnung
```

Further, when I try to use this path to configurre as the interpreter in Pycharm, I am unable to set it.
[image]

But when I create ***`conda env from Pycharm`*** , it creates my env in another path and to activate this using Anaconda Prompt, I have to type full path of created env.

```
conda activate C:\Users\<name>\Anaconda3\envs\Abrechnung
```

I am so confused. Why is this difference and what should be the ideal place to create envs automatically.
What exactly is the difference between `\.conda\envs` folder and `Anaconda3\envs` folder

Comment: How exactly did you create the env? If only doing `conda create -n Abrechnung`, then that wouldn't install anything (just makes an empty env). At minimum, one must specify to include Python `conda create -n Abrechnung python`, and probably want to specify the version (e.g., `python=3.9`).

Comment: Install any package in `Abrechnung` and try again

Answer (score 0):

executable file lies in `C:\Users\******\Anaconda3\env-name\conda.exe`

---

for your another question see this [~/.conda/envs vs. ~/anaconda3/envs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216140/conda-envs-vs-anaconda3-envs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my executable is in C:\Users\<name>\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe. I am still unable to select this created Anaconda environment (at C:\Users\<name>\.conda\envs\Abrechnung) in Pycharm Interpreter. Nor am I able to create environments at C:\Users\<name>\Anaconda3\envs by default in anaconda prompt

Comment: does `C:\Users\<name>\Anaconda3\Abrechnung\conda.exe` exist

Comment: Nope. It exists only inside Scripts folder. Is it possible for me to stop creating ~\.conda folder totally? Not sure why is it automatically getting created. I am assuming that May be if I can get rid of this, Anaconda prompt might create all envs by default at C:\Users\<name>\Anaconda3\envs and not C:\Users\<name>\.conda\envs